# Set a 45° angle as a 0° angle for the accellerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors

Hello everybody I'm developping a game that use the accellerometer to move a sprite in the Y-axis. Everything works well but the problem is that the angle at which the sprite doesn't move is 0°, but this means that when I want to move upwards the sprite I have to turn my hands in an unusual way ... So I thought I could set the base angle to 45 ° so all movements were easier. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about setting a base angle, but you could subtract 45° from your measurements of the accelerometer in your program, which would have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just define base vector,  and calculate difference between it and data received from accelerometer.   I would define base vector on startup,  or average over some time to 
reduce noise ( yes, accelerometers used in mobile devices are pretty low quality )